# Smallest Coprime

Tags: python, function, greatest-common-divisor

I am writing two functions. the first functions goal is to take two numbers as parameters, and return true if they are co-prime and false if otherwise. this function is working properly, and looks like this:

```
from math import gcd #imports GCD function
def check_co_prime(num, M):
    return gcd(num, M) == 1
```

For the second function, I want to take one number, M, as a parameter. And then have it return the smallest coprime of M that is greater than 1. I think theres a way to use the first function to help me write my second function, but I am having trouble. This is what I have, but it hasn't been getting me the desired output.

```
from math import gcd        
def get_smallest_co_prime(M):
    if gcd(M)>1:
        return gcd(M)





    TypeError: gcd() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
from math import gcd        

def check_co_prime(num, M):
    return gcd(num, M) == 1 

def get_smallest_co_prime(M):
    for i in range(2, M): # for every number *i* starting from 2 up to M
        if check_co_prime(i, M): # check if *i* is coprime with M
            return i # if it is, return i as the result
```

Since the algorithm starts from i = 2 and continues in increasing order (i.e. i=2,3,4 etc... ), the first value of i to satisfy the if condition will be the smallest number that is coprime with M.

Comment: Maybe should add a check and an error message if `M` is `2`, because this horrible number is neither `1`, nor does it have any coprimes. The number `2` is just evil. ;)

Comment: Isn't 3 a coprime for 2?

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but I was hoping to get a better understanding of the code as I am a beginner coder and am not looking for purely solutions,but also understanding.

Comment: In plain English, the code says: for every number `i` between 2 and M (`range(2,M)`), check if `i` is coprime with M. If it is coprime with M, then return i. Since the algorithm starts from 2 and increases, the first result that satisfies check_co_prime() will be the smallest number that is coprime with M. - i will add annotation to the code to help explain.